# Coin Change Maker

Tags: python

How would I write this?

Write a complete python program that allows a user to input a number between 0 and 99 which represents cents. The program then tell how many quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies would be needed to make change for this integer. For example an input of 92 would output

This is what i have written so far, i'm used to Java so i think I am mixing in some Java elements

```
a=(int(input("amount")

int p = 0
int n = 0
int d = 0
int q = 0

if(a % 10 != 5)   
    p = (a % 10)
    a -= p

q = a / 25       
    a -= q * 25

d = a / 10       
    a -= d * 10

n = a / 5       
    a -= n * 5

print ("Quarters :" + q)
print ("Dimes :" + d)
print ("Nickels :" + n)
print ("Pennies :" + p)
```

Comment: I think you need to go back and review your textbook/online lesson/notes, because you have syntax errors sprinkled throughout your code.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll review it

Answer (score 1):

This should calculate the number of different types of coins required:

```
a=int(input("Enter amount: ")) #Ask for amount

q = a // 25 #Calculate number of quarters
a -= q*25 #Subtract value of quarters
d = a // 10 #Calculate number of dimes
a -= d*10 #Subtract value of dimes
n = a // 5 #Calculate number of nickels
a -= n*5 #Subtract value of nickels
p = a #Calculate number of pennies



print ("Quarters :" + str(q))
print ("Dimes :" + str(d))
print ("Nickels :" + str(n)) #Print out numbers of coins
print ("Pennies :" + str(p))
```

It first asks for the amount, then calculates the number of quarters required, then subtracts however much money in quarters was required

Answer (score 1):

a greedy algorithm works fine for this(because of the coin denominations) (that is you can always take the biggest denomination that is less than the total due and end up with an optimal solution)

```
def get_next(self,change_due):
    next_coin = max(x for x in [1,5,10,25] if x <= change_due)
    return change_due-next_coin,next_coin

change_due = 99
coins = []
while change_due > 0:
    change_due,next_coin = get_next(change_due)
    coins.append(next_coin)

print coins
```

all that said you can also just solve with math like the other answer.  its also worth noting that if you had a seven cent coin this solution would no longer give you optimal solutions (but the other one wouldnt either)